# Problema no MySQL Connector

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou utilizando MVC 3, EntityFrameWork 4 e banco de dados MySQL. Hospedei minha aplicação na Locaweb. Infelizmente não consigo fazer a mesma conectar ao banco de dados. Rodando a aplicação na minha máquina local e conectando ao banco hospedado na Locaweb funciona perfeitamente. O que fazer?

Comment: Qual erro está dando?

Comment: no momento que acesso o site hospedado e tento fazer a conexão com o banco de dados. na tela de login... liguei na locaweb disseram que é questão de segurança.. por isso quando rodo a aplicação local funciona normalmente. Mas não me souberam dizer a solução rsrs

erro: The underlying provider failed on Open.

Comment: Põe o trecho do código da tua conexão por favor, põe o stack trace também. Uma das prováveis causas é que a Locaweb esteja usando Integrated Security e o user do IIS não tem acesso ao banco, confirma isso com eles. Dá uma lida nisso também: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2012/08/09/error-quot-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open-quot-in-entity-framework-application.aspx

Comment: Poe a solução para gerar o erro na tela, no web.config debugmode=true. Assim quando tu colocar a aplicação no servidor da locaweb ele deve te mostrar o erro.

Comment: Andrew, já está com <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"> preciso fazer mais alguma coisa no controller que faz a primeira chamada ao banco? desculpa é que ainda sou novo no asp.net mvc

tente se conectar, qualquer login vai dar o erro: editorasuperavit.com.br

Comment: Põe o trecho do código c# onde você tenta abrir a conexão. Vamos ver se não tem nada a ver com a transaction.

Comment: então... eu utilizo aquele ado.net edmx... não possuo classe de conexao, ele conecta automaticamente todas as vezes que faço uma requisição, como : Usuarios usuario = db.usuarios.Single(item => item.Login == autenticacao.Login); se quiser e tiver um tempo, posso te mostrar via teamviwer

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3081776/2912399

Comment: Velhinho, exclui essa mensagem acima. Não pode postar dados pessoais aqui, por motivos de segurança.

Comment: tb não deu certo... no catch coloquei para mostrar o stack trace... estou fazendo upload vamos ver que erro vai dar

Comment: Se está funcionando na sua máquina, então provavelmente é uma das 2 coisas, ou o driver do MySQL na locaweb não está instalado ou o user do IIS não tem permissão. Você vai ter que abrir um chamado para eles.

Comment: então já abri um chamado... mas eles demoram 1 dia para responder... pelo jeito vou ter que esperar mesmo! pq realmente esta mto complicado resolver isso! rsrs agradeço muito pela sua ajuda ! assim que eu conseguir resolver posto a solução :)

Comment: Andrew,  da uma olhada no stack

The underlying provider failed on Open. --- at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() at SistemaEditora.Controllers.AutenticacaoController.LogIn(Usuarios autenticacao)

Comment: Testa isso aqui. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2010/12/19/entity-framework-deb.aspx

Comment: Cara consegui, achei uma questão no msdn que a pessoa estava tendo um erro parecido com o meu!

<system.data>
 <DbProviderFactories>
      <clear />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

Comment: era só adicionar este codigo no webconfig.
Muito obrigado pela ajuda continue sempre sendo esse cara gente boa !!!

Comment: Posta isso como resposta. Abraço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionar esta tag no web.config.

`<system.data> <DbProviderFactories> <clear /> <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" /> </DbProviderFactories> </system.data>`

Comment: Parabéns! Agora só faltou clicar no "V" para aceitar essa resposta como solução do problema, ai fica por encerrado esse problema ;)

Comment: obrigado! Sneeps